# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encrypt'

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I would like to generate an RSA key pair, and then write functions to decrypt using the public key and encrypt using the private key.

At the moment I am generating my keys as follows

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as crypto_default_backend


key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        backend=crypto_default_backend(),
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048
    )
private_key = key.private_bytes(
    crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    crypto_serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    crypto_serialization.NoEncryption())
public_key = key.public_key().public_bytes(
    crypto_serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH,
    crypto_serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH
)
```

I then followed the cryptography documentation to encrypt with RSA, it says

```
message = b"encrypted data"
ciphertext = private_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
```

I replaced public_key with private_key.

And to decrypt

```
plaintext = public_key.decrypt(
    ciphertext,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
```

Here I replaced private_key with public_key.

However, running the encrypt part gives me the error "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encrypt'".

How can I fix this?

Comment: The public key is easily calculated if you know the private key (and that's if there is any calculation necessary whatsoever), so what you are saying that you try and achieve makes no sense. What **are** you trying to achieve? If you are trying to generate a signature, read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172). If you are trying to achieve confidentiality, read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3181/1172) (couldn't find a more specific link, but this one should do)

Comment: When you get an exception like `AttributeError` you also get a stacktrace with important information including the line number the exceptions occurs at and the call chain leading up to it. You must include this information in your question, it's almost always helpful and frequently absolutely essential.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, use:

```
public_key = key.public_key()
```

You should not use `public_key = key.public_key().public_bytes(...)` as you will get bytes. You are mixing bytes and key.

Also use the public key to encrypt (not private):

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as crypto_default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes


key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        backend=crypto_default_backend(),
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048
    )
private_key = key.private_bytes(
    crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    crypto_serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    crypto_serialization.NoEncryption())
public_key = key.public_key()
message = b"encrypted data"
ciphertext = public_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
```

Comment: you mixed up public/private to encrypt/decrypt. I added a full encrypt example.